# Question about the authorship of mathematical equation

Tags: publications, ethics

Recently, I felt thrilled because I was finally (after few months of non-stop work) able to mathematically prove the mathematical (physical) transformation which I use to prove some new laws of physics. Everything adds up so nicely using this transformation and everything seems logical. 
To much of my disappointment, I have learned that in 1950's two papers are written where exactly the same mathematical transformation appears. However, in neither of these two papers this mathematical transformation was not proven and it was only guessed from physical laws. Probably because of this lack of proof, both papers were forgotten, otherwise I suppose these papers would be breakthrough papers. These two researchers were not only researchers trying to find the correct form of this transform and in last century there is at least dozen of papers trying to find this transform (although not explicitly stated). 
 Now, I've been able to mathematically prove this transform and I am writing the paper about some new physical laws emerging from this transform. My question is should I mention these papers at all? Since no one before (without fake modesty) was able to prove it and the rest of the papers were on this track (but not explicitly stated) I was thinking about not mentioning these papers at all. Otherwise I would have to explain what these researchers did and its rather irrelevant for my paper (sole discussion about this would represent another paper). What do you people think about this? I would like to hear your opinions, and of course, the constructive criticism from you

Comment: Yes you should reference them.  You can say they _conjectured_ the same transformation formula.

Comment: So, you think it would be wise to write the paragraph or two about the history of transform? The problem is that one of these 1950's authors states that this transform is correct without the shred of mathematical proof and this physicist, although deceased was very influential at the time. One of his peer's, after his death in 2000's stated that his research was breakthrough but it was never accepted as such (probably because of lack of proof). So I would rather skip discussion about this and simply present the derivation of this transform. However, I am not sure this is the best approach

Comment: You should decide how much you want to say about their work based on how much it would contribute to the _narrative_ you want to tell.  A single sentence could be perfectly fine.  That said, don't belittle their works (just be factual: they did not provide proofs) and don't speculate (e.g. on the reason why it didn't revolutionalize the field).

Comment: As a general rule: When in doubt, cite it.

Comment: gallileo skipping that is not proper to the earlier researcher.  It's also not INTERESTING because you are leaving part of the history out.  If, while presenting the history, you can give yourself a little credit (after all it was kind of a lost idea that you rediscovered), I would do that.  [Do it subtley though.]

Comment: You have an opportunity to validate another scientists hard work and contributions, and you don't want to? You would want future generations to treat your work better than that.

Comment: @gallieo1985 So you think it is wise to not mention that  you found prove for a formular that a very influential physicist could only conjecture? Think about the bragging rights you earn :). To be honest this might even make your breakthrough greater because you did something other people were not able to, so give them a heads up. In comparison: Everybody talks about things that Einstein conjectured/foretold and that are just proven today.

Comment: Sincere thanks for answers, I've included proper references to previous work. The root of my doubt came from the fact that I didn't want to accuse prominent physicist of that time that he didn't do the proof nor the derivation of the transform. Although I know this transformation is correct as he wrote it I've expanded it a bit and proven it. I've simply mentioned that the transform appears in somewhat simple form in paper X and Y without the proof . Thanks to all for advice

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If something has appeared, pretty much in any form, you need to cite it. If you don't you will always be open to a charge of plagiarism.

I'll note that the proof is more important, in the grand scheme of mathematics, than the statement of it, so you don't lose anything by citing past work.

Authorship is different from "ownership". You can't own mathematics, but you can copyright your own expression of it (or anything, basically).

But if you don't cite it and someone later asks "why didn't he/she know about this" then it is a negative for you. Always cite your predecessors. Celebrate their work as well as your own advances.

Some of the intervening work has now been put on a firmer ground by your work, but that will only be obvious if you make the connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer, I will be writing about the history of this equation. You helped resolving my dilemma;)

Comment: You have to cite it.  If you can (gracefully) mention that you found the effect before seeing the papers, this would be nice to yourself.  I'm not sure exactly how, but I would give it some shot:  "After deriving this theoretical result, we became aware of earlier experimental work that made these conjectures but did not prove the effects or develop the implications."  Be careful about being too personal, but I would be motivated to give yourself some credit.

Comment: @guest, what you suggest might be appropriate in a memoir, but not in a scientific/mathematical paper. Don't try to make it about _you_. The result and its proof stands on its own. Your proof is all the _credit_ that you need.

Comment: That;s why I said you had to be sly.  Subtle it up a little more, maybe.

Comment: @guest, sorry. No. Do mathematics. Leave it at that. There is no reason to make yourself look foolish in a math paper.

Comment: I think you may still be able to get away with something.  For instance in the context of the introduction where you discuss the motivation and evolution of the study. (Especially if you publish in a science journal, not the holiest of math journals).

Comment: @guest, please stop digging. "get away with something"???? Why don't you think mathematics itself is enough. Primp and preen??? Please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88558/discussion-between-guest-and-buffy).